# Python scopes of nested functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

I did abit of research on namespaces and scopes and saw a somewhat well written answer: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/273302/what-is-the-relationship-between-scope-and-namespaces-in-python

There was this paragraph: "When we say x is in a function's namespace, we mean it is defined there, locally within the function. When we say x is in the function's scope, we mean x is either in the function's namespace or in any of the outer namespaces that the function's namespace is nested inside."

> To test my understanding, correct me if I'm wrong to say for the code below:

a)`x` and `g` are in the namespace of `f`

b)`y` is in the namespace of `g` and also the local scope of `g`

c)`z` and `f` is found in the global scope.

d) scope of `f` is the parent scope of `g`

```
z=5
def f():
    x=5
    def g():
        y=5
        return y
    return g()
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just asking for the answers to a multiple choice quiz.